Azure Data Factory Managed Instance error when connecting to json in data flow
We have a bunch of json files that were downloaded to our ADLS gen2 account in a particular file path in a container (container\firstDir\SecondDir\myfile.json) that were downloaded from an API in a previous step using the same linked service for the dataset as a sink.
When i try to build a data flow to read the json files to flatten them out and store them in a table i get an error saying:

at Source 'source1': Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, https://myconnection/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90 When using Managed Identity(MI)/Service Principal(SP) authentication

For source: In Storage Explorer, grant the MI/SP at least Execute permission for ALL upstream folders and the file system, along with Read permission for the files to copy. Alternatively, in Access control (IAM), grant the MI/SP at least the Storage Blob Data Reader role.
For sink: In Storage Explorer, grant the MI/SP at least Execute permission for ALL upstream folders and the file system, along with Write permission for the sink folder. Alternatively, in Access control (IAM), grant the MI/SP at least the Storage Blob Data Contributor role.
Also please ensure that the network firewall settings in the storage account are configured correctly as turning on firewall rules for your storage account blocks incoming requests for data by default, unless the requests originate from a service operating within an Azure Virtual Network (VNet) or from allowed public IP addresses.


If i go to the source dataset and click on the "test connection" it returns successful and if i click on "preview data" i can see the data in the json file just fine.
I have also gone to the storage account that it will be reading the data from and it has "Storage Blob Data Contributor" and "Storage Blob Data Reader". According to other posts i have read, this is all that is needed.
No idea where to go from here as I am new to data factory.

The error message suggests that the MI/SP does not have the necessary permissions to access the files. Grant the required permissions as stated in error message

@Aswin All of the necessary grants were given prior to posting this post and I still got the error above. I have a ticket open with Microsoft in addition to this post.
